# How to test a JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services, unit-testing, testing

I'm putting together a JSON API which may or may not be built with 
Rails. I'd like to be able to verify that the JSON API is behaving as 
expected by testing it from a test client that only communicates via 
HTTP.

For example, the test client will send a request to a given URL on the 
test server, and then verify that the response is a JSON string equal 
to what is expected by the specs. The response may also be an HTTP 
response code such as a 401.

I'm currently running tests with QUnit and jQuery.ajax. It works, but 
I'm wondering if there's a better option. Has anyone else done 
something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually I test apis as part of the codebase - this is for good reasons, like: the api codebase having tests for documentation; errors show you run the test suite after making a refactor; it's easier to track down issues with the tests; they run as part of continuous integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the python requests library. I've used it for just such a purpose and it is awesome.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Any language with a decent HTTP library and a JSON library ought to do. Just pick your favorite language and testing framework and go for it. I'd probably use [RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec) and [Rack::Test](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack-test/0.6.1/frames), especially if the API will be implemented in Ruby, but tastes vary.

*Edit:* You mentioned you'd like to run the tests outside the server. If you're sure about that then use e.g. [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) instead of Rack::Test.

Comment: We're trying to gather requirements as a series of tests before choosing a language or framework. We won't know what to look for in a framework before we have our tests/requirements.

Comment: good comment, totally on point.  any test framework should easily support this. I'd also recommend having the tests live in a plugin that can be included on the API codebase so you can more easily run them when you've only checked out the API codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Usually API is regular controllers/actions. So you can test this actions as regular controller inside of server app. Thats like i test my API actions:

```rb
describe Api::AccountsController do
  describe "GET :index" do
    it "should be success" do
      do_get
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should return list of accounts" do
      5.times{ Factory :account }
      do_get
      JSON.parse(response.body).size.should == 5
    end

    it "should return id, name and description of each account" do
      account = Factory :account
      do_get
      result = JSON.parse(response.body).first
      result['account']['id'].should == account.id
      result['account']['name'].should == account.name
      result['account']['description'].should == account.description
    end

    def do_get
      get :index, :format => :json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The solution needs to communicate over HTTP and be server framework agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a JS API for Rails and built a whole set of tests using **QUnit** and **jQuery**. I was quite happy with the end result, my aim was to test the API thoroughly and **this combination of tools was everything I needed**.

I've been working on a new project that uses **Jasmine**, its a bit more descriptive in the way you write tests (which makes the Business Analysts happy) but the end result was much the same as QUnit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some have found success with cucumber (checkout this similar question)

[What is the recommended method of testing a JSON client-server api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376479/what-is-the-recommended-method-of-testing-a-json-client-server-api/1388218#1388218)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mpartel completely.

You'll presumably want a set of unit tests (without the complexity of HTTP) to test the logic of your implementation. Once you go down that route, you'll find that there will be a benefit in writing the tests in the same language.

For example, you if you write it in Rails (and use Rack::Test), you'll also be able to unit test lots of the cases in a simpler Test::Unit (or RSpec) environment.

Comment: We're trying to gather requirements as a series of tests before choosing a language or framework. We won't know what to look for in a framework before we have our tests/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is controller tests using rspec

```
describe PersonApiController 
  # GET /person/1.json
  it "should respond with a person" do 
     person = Person.create(:name => "scott")
     get :show, :id => person.id, :format => 'json'
     response.should be_success
     response.body.should have_selector('name', :content => person.name)
  end
end
```

If you want to get even fancier, you can share a api client via a plugin/gem between your client code and your server code and then initialize it using the json like

```
person_client = PersonClient.new(response.body)
person_client.name.should eql 'scott'
```

Comment: Controller tests suck. Use Cucumber instead.

Comment: For user-facing stuff, no. Controller tests demonstrably do the wrong things and should be entirely avoided.

For API stuff, it's borderline.

Very little in software development is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Note my qualification. For APIs, it's borderline.

Comment: We may not be using Rails. The solution needs to communicate over HTTP and be server framework agnostic.

Comment: Cucumber's an easy install. Test::Unit is the wrong tool for this situation (or almost any other) because it encourages the testing of *implementation* instead of *behavior*.

Comment: @ScottSchulthess You can keep saying "opinion" all you like, but that doesn't change the fact that some tools are objectively better than others.

Comment: @ScottSchulthess IMHO a lot of the Ruby community has dropped Cucumber for the wrong reasons—they actually *do*, objectively, need to be using it, and they don't understand why. (I try to explain this whenever I can, but it involves tough concepts that I find difficult to verbalize and many people find difficult to understand.) "intended to be written by business owners."—well, maybe, but Gherkin is just as useful for the developer to read 6 months later as it is for a business owner to read. API testing is an edge case, but UI testing is *demonstrably harmed* without Cucumber or similar.

Comment: @ScottSchulthess I could as easily say that when a lot of smart people *do* use Cucumber, the approach of "it's too hard, I don't need it" is not correct. Not everything correct is self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

Just write some specs with Cucumber and/or RSpec to connect to your app and test the output. No need to drag JQuery into it.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this?

Comment: What do you need examples of? Just use Capybara or Rack::Test to `visit` or `post` to the appropriate URL, then call `JSON.parse page.driver.response.body` or something like that and test the result.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.soapui.org/

a functional testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! This is how to do it with vanilla Rails. Notice the different accept mime type. You may parse the JSON if you wish. Comparing as strings was sufficient.

```
  test "vote comment up" do
    # @request.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    @request.headers["Accept"] = "application/javascript"
    post :up, {post_id: 1, id: 1}, {user_id: 5}
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal @response.body, '{"error":true,"errorPath":"/users/5/balance","userVotes":1,"totalVotes":0}'
  end
```

If you want to test during development, I use [Advanced Rest Client Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher).